# NGINX with Express.js & socket.io | Cannot GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, socket.io

I have a `node/express.js/socket.io` app setup on an Ubuntu Server running on port 3002. I've opened up all ports on the machine.

When I go to `11.111.111.1:3002/` everything works perfectly (both socket.io & express.js). I'm trying to proxy-pass the app to `/mediaDev/` which seems to work in that I get an error message from express.js or node which says:

> "Cannot GET /mediaDev"

Where as either not finding the node app returns 502 Bad Gateway.

But going directly to the app at my IP address plus port the app works perfectly just as expected.

Simplified NGINX:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name _;

  location ~ ^/mediaDev {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
  }
}
```

node.js related to serving content:

```
var app = express()
app.user(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index')
})

var server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log("listening on port 3002")
})

var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  path: '/mediaDev/socket.io'
})
```

Note: on the IP address both express.js and socket.io are working. On the actual domain express returned the error but my socket.io path `/mediaDev/socket.io` still works.

I thought the above was a bit strange. If I'm proxy passing `/mediaDev` and making my socket.io path `/mediaDev/socket.io` shouldn't I expect an error and that to actually be at `/mediaDev/mediaDev/socket.io`?

Comment: Are you trying to proxy_pass the entire connection to port 3002 or just proxy socket.io?

Comment: The entire connection

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For NGINX, it matters if you add a trailing slash to the URI (both in `location` and in `proxy_pass`). If you set it up properly, you can have it strip the prefix from the request path.

Try this:

```
location /mediaDev/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/;
}
```

With this, a request to NGINX for `/mediaDev/` will be "translated" to the request for "/" for Express. And it serves as a prefix, so `/mediaDev/socket.io` on the NGINX side will request `/socket.io` on the Express side.

Comment: When I use 'http://localhost:3002/;' with the trailing slash I get an nginx error. "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named locatoin, or ..."

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride and you changed the `location` too? You'll get that error if you keep using `~ ^/mediaDev`

Answer (score 0):

Finding that doing the following gives me the desired behavior but if someone wants to give a better answer I feel this solution isn't ideal.

```
app.get('/mediaDev', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index')
})
```

This method seems to require me to hard-code the location I want to use in nginx into my node.js application. Ideally I'm hoping for a more modular solution.